# CPropertyPage dialogue OnOk should not close the dialogue if there is an error

Tags: mfc, cdialog, cpropertysheet

I have a class which inherits from `CPropertyPage` class. I have a `OnOk()` method and a `OnKillActive()` method.
Whenever I press Ok on the dialogue. `OnKillActive()` gets called but `OnOk()` is never called.
The problem is depending on a condition I do not want to close the dialogue on pressing Ok. But the dialogue is closing on pressing Ok.

How do I prevent the dialogue from closing when I press Ok?

Code:

```
In MyClass.h:
    class MyClass : public CPropertyPage {
    }

In MyClass.cpp:
    void MyClass::OnOK(){
        if (condition true) {
            return; // This should prevent the dialogue from closing but still      the dialogue closes
        }
        return CPropertyPage::OnOk();
    }

    BOOL MyClass::OnKillActive() {
        if (condition true) {
            CDialog::DoModal();
            return FALSE; // This should prevent the dialogue from closing but   still the dialogue closes
        }
        return CPropertyPage::OnKillActive();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in the `OnClickedOk()` function of the `PropertySheet` class, there was an `EndDialog(IDOK)`. This is why it was closing everytime when Ok was pressed.

I just gave a condition check before `EndDialog()` and it worked.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can call `CDialog::DoModal();` as your property page is  not closed yet.

When this event(`OnKillActive()`) occurs your property page is **inactive**. But your property page still exists and the data in the property page also exists for validation.

To bring your page back, just set the focus in one of the dialog item. Use "`GetDlgItem`" to get an object and set the focus using "`SetFocus`"

An example is available here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2122ct0z.aspx