# Conditionally stopping a CPropertySheet from closing from the page OnOK button handler

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cmfcpropertypage

I have just encountered an issue with `CPropertyPage`.

I have been trying to use the `OnOK` handler to do some validation:

```
void CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::OnOK()
{
    bool bHandle = false;

    UpdateData(TRUE);

    // AJT v20.2.0 — We need to pass "true" so that the error message will display!
    if (ValidSettings(true))
    {
        bHandle = true;
        SaveSettings();
    }

    if (bHandle)
        CMFCPropertyPage::OnOK();
}
```

The problem is, the sheet still closes down. I had hoped that preventing the `CMFCPropertyPage::OnOK` would have stopped the sheet closing. But it doesn't.

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154555/cpropertypage-dialogue-onok-should-not-close-the-dialogue-if-there-is-an-error) that the **sheet's** `OnOK` is making a `EndDialog(IDOK)` call. But i don't want to complicate my sheet. The testing is here in this page. so I need a was for the sheet to know if it should close or not when user clicks the OK button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the [`OnCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#oncommand) handler of your property page's parent *property sheet* class and intercept the clicks for the `IDOK` command (which will be given in the `wParam` parameter). If you **do not** call the base class `OnCommand` but *still return* `TRUE` to indicate that your have handled the command, then the property sheet will not close:

```cpp
BOOL MyPropertySheet::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == IDOK) { // OK button clicked...
        if (!ValidSettings(true)) return TRUE; // NOT valid, prevent further processing.
    }
    // You can also intercept the "Apply" command by testing for ID_APPLY_NOW

    // Everything is OK, so continue processing ...
    return CMFCPropertySheet::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

Note that I have assumed your parent is derived from `CMFCPropertySheet`, but the same works for the 'older' `CPropertySheet`.

Comment: My problem is that I have two sheets, both with this `ValidSettings` method. As it stands I can only call this method for the active page (which I do not know how to detect). When I try to run it for the page (not visible) I get an assertion. I need a way to validate the settings for both pages. For example, if I and on page 1 and go to page 2, and page 1 does not have valid settings, it stop not allow going to page 2. Vice versa. And Ok as above, if we click OK, BUT only  validate the active page (somehow).

Comment: At the moment I have added `OnKillActive` to each page. In there it does the validation and flags the user. Then, in the sheets `OnCommand` I just use `GetActivePage` and compare the handles. It then knows which to perform validation on. It working ok!